# Delegate in Python in combination with unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

i have some c# code a snippet taken from a Unity3D tutorial

```
AddListener(delegate {print(i);}
```

I want to do this in python i need a container to pass i to print, however Unity does not accept partial

```
TypeError: expected UnityAction, got partial
```

please help me

```
AddListener(Lambda i: print(i))
```

should work but somehow i dont manage to spell the function right i always get:

() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

with IronPython aswell as with normal python.

Here a bigger sniped of what i want to do:

```
browser(enter=holderdict,itemy=0,*a):
    for item in enter["template"]:
        kgo = GameObject()
        kgo.AddComponent[RectTransform]()
        kgo.name=str(item)
        butn = kgo.AddComponent[Button]()
        butn.onClick.AddListener(lambda butn: browser(item))
```

okay i solved the question so far the problem was not in Lambda but in how i called browser this is right:

```
butn.onClick.AddListener(lambda butn: browser(holderdict[item]))
```

but i still have a problem: Lambda does not safe the item it is supposed to pass in the loop it instead just passes the last one of the loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i finally managed to get Lambda working:

```
butn.onClick.AddListener(lambda item=item: dicbrowser(holderdict[item],0))
```